# Diferença entre android.content e android.support.v4.content

Tags: android

Quando eu faço uso do Fragments ou do AsyncTaskLoader, aparece duas opções referente ao mesmo elemento: `android.content` e `android.support.v4.content`

Qual a diferença entre as duas?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essas são as configurações do meu projeto:

```
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 23
```

Comment: Toda lib dentro do package `support` serve para adicionar compatibilidade de uma API com versões mais antigas do Android. [Veja a documentação oficial](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[android.content](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/package-summary.html) refere-se a um *namespace* existente no SDK Android cuja versão da API é aquela indicada em *compileSdkVersion*.

[android.support.v4.content](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/package-summary.html) refere-se a um *namespace* existente na biblioteca ***support-v4***.
Ela é incluída no projecto quando usa, no *build.gradle*, `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'`

As bibliotecas de suporte destinam-se a disponibilizar classes e métodos que existem nas versões mais recentes do SDK de forma a poderem ser usadas em dispositivos com versões antigas do SDK onde essas classes e métodos não existiam.

A razão porque lhe aparece mais de uma opção é por a mesma classe existir em ambos os *namespace*.